# WARN: No coverage recordings found. No report will be generated

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, clover

Steps that bring to this warning

1. Create simple maven project
2. In pom.xml add maven-clover2-plugin and reporting plugin
3. from command line

   mvn clean install
   mvn clover2:clean
   mvn clover2:instrument - > after this step coverage.db is generated
   mvn clover2:aggregate
   mvn clover2:clover OR run the HtmlReportRunner.java, which is taken from your site (https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/HtmlReporter)

After the last step the following warning is displayed - WARN: No coverage recordings found. No report will be generated.

The things are different when instead of running from command line, running from Eclipse by:

```
enabling clover on project
run the specific class from configuration as "Run Clover as"
run HtmlReportRunner.java
```

After these three steps report is generated.
When run by Eclips  generated additional .db file
My point is to make it work when running from cmd.

Will appreciate any kind of help/suggestion

Thanks,

Sevak

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
mvn clover2:instrument clover2:clover
```

This should generate the DB and create the report.

(I think the aggregate goal is not needed when you have a simple (non-multi-module) project.)